# Retrieving iCloud Note Tables Through Web Service But Table Cells Are Out Of Order In The Response

Tags: icloud, computer-forensics

I've gone through some forensic analysis and implemented iCloud Account access programmatically (with authentication).
The problem I'm facing is that, when getting responses for Notes Table attachment, the table cells are out of order. E.g. sometimes the cells from the 2nd row appears first, and cells from the 1st row comes next. I couldn't find any meta data from which I can know the ordering of these cells.

FYI, I have decoded the attachment responses with **Versioned-Document** and **Crframework** protocall-buffer objects. If someone has worked with this technology or followed similar forensic analysis, can you help me getting order of the table cell data?

Thanks in advance.